# How to target sub-nav and toggle only one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I toggle the secondary navigation links after clicking the "HEADER" button (under the "this should toggle the ul links"), and only one at a time. When the user clicks the button, it should close any other subnav links at its level, only allowing one to be open at a time. It should also be able to close, without triggering the other to open.

```
  <div class="inner">
  <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"> <span>HEADER</span> </button>
  <div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: block;">
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <li class="list-header mobile"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.list-header').next('div').toggle();
$('.list-header').click(function() {
  $('.list-header').next('div').slideUp();
  $(this).next('div').toggle();
  return false;
});

$('.mobile').next('div').toggle();
$('.mobile').click(function() {
  $('.mobile').next('div').slideUp();
  $(this).next('div').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/jdkwcpva/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solves your issue:

```
$('.mobile').next('ul').toggle();    // <-- .next('ul') instead of .next('div')
$('.mobile').click(function() {
  $('.mobile').next('ul').slideUp(); // <-- same
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();       // <-- same
  return false;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jdkwcpva/4)**</kbd>

Comment: I know this is a separate question, but what would be the best way to toggle an icon set with `:after` pseudo class, so that the icon returns to its initial state after clicking the other sub link?

Comment: Use an additional class for the active sub link, so you would have in your CSS `.mobile:after` and `.mobile.active:after` with a different icon for each rule.

Comment: @user3438917 You can upvote my answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: It appears its not a matter of adding a pseudo class, but toggling the previously opened sections icon back to its original state. I believe I need a way to rotate the icon back to its state after the `.next('ul').slideUp();` function, but having an issue applying the css to that class by targeting the previously opened div.

Comment: Here's a better example of what I need to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/jdkwcpva/7/

Comment: thanks for all the help! I've got it working now, but having trouble getting the main nav toggles to work correctly. They should be switching the `+` and `-` correctly, depending on their state. When another main nav is opened, the previously opened main nav should return to a `+`. I figure it should be similar to the subnav, but not quite sure: https://jsfiddle.net/jdkwcpva/9/